# Object Not Found error using .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working on a project in my localhost which root folder is

localhost/freelancer/sitename/

Now when I access a page for e.g login.php which URL is **sitename/login** then it's showing me an error message:

```
Object not found!
```

Here is the .htaccess file which I am running:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/freelancer/sitename/not-found.php
ErrorDocument 500 http://localhost/freelancer/sitename/not-found.php


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ menu-details.php?city=$1&mid=$2&title=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ booking.php?city=$1&mid=$2&title=$3&action=$4 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ city.php?city=$1 [QSA,L]
```

why is this error message showing when accessing any page?

Note: In the live server, it's working fine!!

Answer (score 2):

It's working now.

I just remove this line:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Thanks.